# ASIHTTPRequest .Net Webservice parser

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap, asynchronous, asihttprequest

I am making a xml/soap request class which gets data asynchronously from .NET web service. I call this class from another class which is a View Controller. Now the problem is that as it is asynchronous i don't have the idea when the result will come and delegates be fired, and need to return the data to view controller class.

**Question**: How would I wait in view controller Class for data?

*Note: Can't use Notification*

Comment: You don't wait for data; once the delegates have all the information required (or enough to display something) **they** update the view controller with the information.  Else it would behave as if it was a synchronous request.

Comment: Yes exactly, soo i am calling asihttprequest class into a GCD or NSOperationQueue block now working fine. Just canceling this request is creating problem. Thanks for your response :)